# Workaround for aux socket partial damage

Tags: audio, headphone-jack

So basically, I must have damaged the jack socket of my Redmi Note 3 (OS: Android 6.0.1 MMB29M) - now with any kind of headset (I've tried many!) I can only hear some audio channels, while the rest is almost completely cut out (plays at extremely low volume - it can be barely heard). For example, I can typically only hear instrumentals, and not voice, while listening to music - irrespective of the audio player I'm using.

Plus, my phone does not really detect headphones when I plug them in, so I had to resort to the [LesserAudioSwitch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nordskog.LesserAudioSwitch) app that, if I understood it correctly, forces the phone to use the "headphones" audio out even if it detects no plugged device.

To try and understand what the problem is, I downloaded the app [Stereo Test for speakers & headphones](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andromo.dev578695.app665236&hl=en) and run a test. What I get is that I can hear perfectly clear sound when I test the `L` channel, and the same when I test the `R` channel, BUT I only hear extremely low and distant sound when I test them `Both`.

This makes me think (but I could well be wrong) that these three choices correspond physically to three separately wired channels in the jack, and that one of them is not working properly. I would like to know if this is true, and if there would be any way to redirect audio from one channel to another in order to be able to properly listen to music - even at the price of sacrificing stereo sound.

Bonuses:

1 - Actually my Bose PC speakers are recognized correctly by my phone and with them none of the described issues takes place; they just work perfectly. I cannot understand why (???).
2 - I DON'T have any option for balancing or switching between mono/stereo mode on my phone, not in the accessibility settings nor anywhere else (if there's something, it is incredibly well hidden...).

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: A possible practical solution, at least for music, that in my case worked is to leave the phone as it is and pre-process (via Audacity, for instance) all music to be put in it splitting stereo tracks in two mono tracks and balancing them such that one is "full L" and the other "full R". This way I can hear sound from both speakers without issues apart from the fact of having sacrificed stereo sound. It's not a cost-efficient solution, I would say, but it does the job.

Comment: Just to add the obvious alternates: have you tried with different wired headphones? and bluetooth headphones?

Comment: I did! All headphones give me the same issues; the same is true for aux connections to my home stereo or my car stereo; for some reason the only successful aux connection I can make is with my Bose speakers. Bluetooth outputs (car,  speakers, headphones)  always work just fine.